# Model Building on Remote Database

Tags: python, r, database, postgresql, data-science

Our client has some data that is in their database and I have to build a statistical model on this.

But the client is worried about data security. Is there anyway I can make sure that the data is not stored at all on my PC. The client basically does not want to the data to be taken out of their environment.

Is there anyway I can comply with this requirement?

The client uses a PostgreSQL Db and I am using R for modelling

Comment: That's a fantastic and important question, quite a bit of which is not specific to R. You could disable saving your R environment on exit. To be ultra-conservative, you should disable any virtual memory, as swap space (if used) can persist. Technically there are cold-boot techniques for sniffing RAM, but physical security should preclude them. I suggest you generalize this away from `[r]` and `[postgresql]`, since the problem is common to anybody contracting to a remote database.

Comment: You might suggest that they put up a local-to-them instance of `rstudio-server` and give you access rights. It ensures all data is processed on their site and not on your computer, and still allows you to use your language-of-choice. (Note that this can be done free as long as they otherwise control access to the rstudio instance. For instance, I open the server on a local-only port and strictly control ssh access with port forwarding to that local port. The docs for tightening ssh to this level are good enough, I haven't found a way around it yet.)

Comment: @r2evans : thnx... I have edited the question as requested.